# How to change color for overlay view behind presented UIMenu?

Tags: ios, swift, uimenu

This is how it simply look like:

[image]

and I would like to set opaque black color for behing view when UIMenu is presented. Is it possible?

I simply do it like this:

```
let menu = UIMenu(title: "") // shortened
addButton.menu = menu
```

Comment: Which view do you want to set opaque?

Comment: @HidayetOzsoy the view behind the UIMenu. To make it less visible. Everything under menu.